# CPU Temparature above threshold

Tags: cpu, overheating

My PC is running Ubuntu 14.04 currently. For last two days, the PC does not turn on. On running recovery mode, the message "CPU Temperature above threshold" shows. Sometimes the PC do start, only to shut itself off showing a scrolling message "Thermal Shutdown". 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the computer and check if fans are working.
If so, open the case and try to clean them (and clean all the rest if possible).
Good luck!

Comment: Make sure to check if your thermal paste is still "ok".